# Rails undefined method `collect' for 1:Fixnum, how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

hi i've upgraded from rails 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 and got this error:

```
undefined method `collect' for 1:Fixnum
```

in this code snipped:

```
   @data[:weekday] ||= XYZ.count(:include => [:membership], 
                       :conditions => ["xyz.done_at IS NOT NULL AND memberships.course_id = ?", @course_id],
             :group => "WEEKDAY(xyz.done_at)").collect {| val | [val[0].to_i, val[1]]}
```

problem specially ocurrs in this part

```
.collect {| val | [val[0].to_i, val[1]]}
```

what could be the problem?

after changing to where I have this:

```
@data[:weekday] ||= XYZ.joins("membership").where("done_at IS NOT NULL AND memberships.course_id = ?", @course_id).group("WEEKDAY(done_at)").collect {| val | [val[0].to_i, val[1]]}
```

and got this error:

```
Error: Unknown table 'xyz': SELECT `xyz`.* FROM `xyz` membership WHERE (done_at IS NOT NULL AND memberships.course_id = 2) GROUP BY WEEKDAY(done_at)
```

Schema.rb

```
  create_table "xyz", :force => true do |t|
t.datetime "send_at"
t.datetime "done_at"
t.string   "hash_for_url",    :null => false
t.integer  "membership_id",   :null => false
t.integer  "lesson_text_id"
t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
t.text     "json_answers"
t.boolean  "worked"
t.boolean  "passed"
t.boolean  "checked"
t.datetime "opened_at"
t.text     "rendered_result"
t.datetime "remind_at"
end

add_index "xyz", ["done_at"], :name => "index_xyz_on_done_at"
add_index "xyz", ["membership_id"], :name => "index_xyz_on_membership_id"
add_index "xyz", ["send_at"], :name => "index_xyz_on_send_at"
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of `schema.rb` in the question.

Comment: which parts do you need?

Comment: The parts relating to the XYZ model.

Comment: added above the parts

Comment: hast du mir nen tipp?

Comment: sorry last one was in german :P ... do you have a hint for me how to solve this issue?

Comment: could you explain what you want to achieve with this part of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling collect method on XYZ.count.

XYZ.count will return the Fixnum and collect is method of array. If you really want to use collect then you should use where instead of count. where returns Array. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but not really ;) ... when I change .count with .where then I can use the .collect

Comment: Have you run your migrations?

Comment: why should I do this? Nothing changed on data-schema.

Comment: Because the error is telling you the table doesn't exist.  You can check by opening up `rails console` and entering `XYZ.connection`  I don't think you want to use `#collect` though. It seems like you want to get the count of certain groups, is that right?